# Why is id of two strings different?

Tags: python, string

Can anyone tell me why following code gives different answers?

```
>>> a='3x'
>>> b='3x'
>>> a is b
True

>>> a='3[x'
>>> b='3[x'
>>> a is b
False
```

--- EDIT ---

Thanks for the comment from Jean, so their ids are different because the strings are not cached, that make sense.

The thing that interested me is, when I try this in the [PythonTutor website](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%3D'3%5Bx'%0Ab%3D'3%5Bx'%0Aprint%28a%20is%20b%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=3&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) it returns True.

Comment: you should use `==` not `is`

Comment: string interning works in mysterious ways. Where there are non-alphanum characters it doesn't cache. I have changed the duplicate link.